# Affine Parameter Optimization using simulated annealing

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project to compare images in the database. I use color and gradient orientation as  features of the image and these features are not rotation invariance, therefore to compare well I proposed to warp the images using 5 parameter affine transformation and optimise the 5 parameters to obtain the best match between the images.

For image comparison I use histogram matching distance within the range of 0-1 therefore 1 represents the best match. I set the threshold of match to 0.75 (this is the fitness function).

However, as I am not familiar with simulated annealing method, I am confused if it can be used to optimise the parameters of affine transformation matrix. I read other methods like Genetic algorithm, and cross entropy optizmiation but I found Simulated annealing more understandable but I am not sure if it can do the job.

Although this might be a more theoretical question than coding, I just want to confirm my doubts. I have implemented the codes for simulated annealing and it seems to be working well but not that fast in terms of optimisation. Please confirm if u think that theoretical simulated annealing can be used in my project. I have no problem with my coding so I won't put up any codes.

Comment: Why are you picking those features (colour and gradient orientation)? Why would you need to warp the image at all, and why use a 5 parameter affine transformation?

Comment: what are u commenting? 
If u don't know about the question please don't comment unnecessarily.